# Difference between IT and THAT

Tags: pronouns

> here will be nobody else. No formalities are necessary, you know. **It**
>   will be a good idea if you drop by my office around six o'clock on
>   Friday so that we may both go to my place together.

I wonder whether the pronoun "it" in the sentence "it will be a good idea" could be replaced with the pronoun "that"? And in this sentence what does the pronoun "it" refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No formalities are necessary, you know. It
>   will be a good idea if you drop by my office around six o'clock on
>   Friday so that we may both go to my place together.

**It** is so-called "dummy" or "expletive" it.  It acts a placeholder, as a proxy subject. This structure using **it** divides a simple subject-verb-complement utterance

> Dropping by my office around six o'clock on Friday will be a good
>   idea.

into two pieces, in order to put some emphasis on the first piece:

> It will be a good idea  | if you drop by my office around six o'clock
>   on Friday.

The speaker is making a *suggestion*, although in a somewhat circuitous manner. Paraphrase: **You *should* come to my office...**

If you wanted to substitute **that** for **it**, you would have to change the order of the clauses, since **that** as demonstrative pronoun refers to something already mentioned or present:

> If you come to my office around six o'clock on Friday, **that** would be a
>   good idea.

Dummy / placeholder **it** as proxy subject can *anticipate* the actual semantic subject.  Demonstrative pronoun **that** must *refer back* to one.

These are colloquial statements which strike a casual tone.

Comment: Thanks. I totally got it. Your explanation is beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the 'it', that is fine.

I would change the 'it will be a good idea' to 'it would be a good idea', as it is a conditional.